# Custom cell code showing leaks in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

this may be a simple question but i can't figure the solution.Im creating a custom cell for a table view.When I'm testing the app instruments is showing leaks in code used for creating custom cell.I don't understand where i have to release the stuff for removing the leaks.Can anyone give me a hand for this.
This is the code i used for creating the custom cell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellID= @"Parcustom";
    Parcustom *cell = (Parcustom *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if(cell==nil)
    {


        NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Parcustom" owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in nibObjects)
        {
            if([currentObject isKindOfClass: [Parcustom class]])
            {
                cell = (Parcustom *)currentObject;
            }

        }
    }    // Configure the cell...
        cell.f1.text=[datedisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




           cell.f2.text=[tips objectAtIndex:[[indexx objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]intValue]];
                  cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;             
    return cell;

}
```

The instrument is saying leak in the line  NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Parcustom" owner:nil options:nil];
How can i remove this leak.Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no leak in the code presented. I suppose actual leak is somewhere in `Parcustom` class. Perhaps you don't release some ivar in `Parcustom`'s `dealloc`. Maybe `f1` or `f2`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace below code with if block

```
NSArray *nibObjects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Parcustom" owner:nil options:nil]];

    for(id currentObject in nibObjects)
    {
        if([currentObject isKindOfClass: [Parcustom class]])
        {
            cell = (Parcustom *)currentObject;
        }

    }
    [nibObjects release];
```

Comment: thanks for your hand.but it is still showing leaks sometimes.can i make nibobjects=nil;and then release it

Comment: you can do that.one thing if Custom cell with out xib you never get this type of problems

Comment: Thanks for the great help.no i was not release the two labels created for custom cell and by releasing that solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a leak in your code - Try running the static analyzer ("Analyze" in XCode's menu) and see if it reports a leak. If it does, you can expand the information about the leak and see the root cause.